# Get Spawned .exe of windows service via command line

Tags: windows, powershell

On the windows command line (preferably powershell), how can I see the process that a service spawns? using the powershell cmdlet `get-service | select *`, none of the properties for the service objects have anything to do with a spawned process.

Surely there is a way to view what a service does via powershell.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Are you aware that, especially on older Windows versions or low-RAM machines, most services don't spawn their own process but instead run in a common "host" process - typically an instance of svchost.exe - that has the relevant account and permissions? Are you only interested in services that run in their own process, or do you also want to find the host process of any service even if it's sharing with other services? Also, do you want the service's host process only, or do you also want child processes spawned from the host process?

Answer (score 0):

This powershell command will display the name, description, and image path of all services in the provided registry key.

`get-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\*' | select DisplayName, Description, ImagePath | format-list`

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the name and details of the process hosting a service, you can use the Windows built-in CLI program `tasklist.exe` for that. The following command works in both CMD and PowerShell:

```
tasklist /FI "SERVICES eq <ServiceName>"
```

where `<ServiceName>` is the actual name of the service (usually not the same as the "Display Name", which is intended to be human-readable). Note that despite the `SERVICES eq` filter rule, this command will successfully identify a process that hosts multiple services, even if only a single service is specified on the command line. You can add the `/SVC` flag to get the list of all services running in the process. `tasklist.exe /?` will print help information for the command in general.